# Finding maximum value of a date column using sparklyr in databricks

Tags: r, databricks, sparklyr

I am just trying to find the maximum value of a date column using a data imported using sparklyr in databricks:

`data %>% dplyr::select(date_variable) %>% max()`

This returns an error:

```
Error in max(.) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument Error in max(.) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

If I just do `max(data$date_variable)`, it gives `-inf`. Surely `max()` and `min()` have to be one of the most used functions out there? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")

data <- sdf_sql(sc, "SELECT DATE('2020-01-01') AS date_variable UNION SELECT DATE('2020-01-02') AS date_variable")
```

`data` is a Spark data frame. The result of `select` is still a Spark data frame which can't be used with `max`.

```
data %>% dplyr::select(date_variable) %>% class()
#> [1] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"
```

There are two main ways to get the max value.

If you use `pull`, the result is a `Date` vector which can be used with `max`.

```
data %>% dplyr::pull(date_variable) %>% max()
#> [1] "2020-01-02"
```

The downside of this method is that the computation isn't done in Spark. To do the computation in Spark, use `summarise`.

```
data %>% dplyr::summarise(max_date = max(date_variable))
#> # Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
#>   max_date  
#>   <date>    
#> 1 2020-01-02
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I did get the required value using the summarize function but even this is like taking too long - 2 minutes. Is there a better way of doing this? Also Is pull similar to collect? I am very new to sparklyr, not so new to working in RStudio.